# Spring data persistence column user1_.id does not exist exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I was following [this guide](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/19/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot)
and I am getting

`mvnw spring-boot:run
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user1_.id does not exist`
The complete source code is [here](https://github.com/lackorol/springdata)
The tables are created and Spring data seems to work just findByName in
Initializer class makes troubles.

Comment: The code is similar like in guide so I uploaded it on github.

Comment: I have compared User class with other classes you have, in User class your id is string, on the others it is long. Does this have anything to do with your error?

Comment: Good catch but still the same error even with id : Long

Answer (score 0):

You can't use name of table for your database as `User` try change this name

[postresql doc](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/9.4/sql-keywords-appendix)

You can write this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "SITE_USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

It's work for me

Comment: This doesn't help I have tried before. Have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake

Comment: The error doesn't have nothing in common with name of table user_group.
I have tried rename it. Its something with User id.

Comment: try use mvn clean spring-boot:run

Comment: Remove all tables from your DB or set property 

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create instead of update value

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is User table, because Group/Event have define relation with user, so you can't save without user in table group/event.

1. Delete all old table, then change name table user to any name to generate user table.
2. Add user entity to 2 table Event/group
   Note: Sorry, i'm chicken in stackoverflow, i have run it on my code without problem

   ```
   @Table(name="temp_user")
   public class User {

       @Id
       private Long id;
       private String name;
       private String email;
   }
   ```

[image: 2.Add user]

Log:

[image]

Comment: Why there is record User(id=6, name=null, email=null), when you provided (null, "dawd", "awdaw")?

Comment: This is log for Group/Event table, because table(group/event) only have field user_id is key relationship with table user, so the record only have user_id, but log of saving table user will have full information.